# Replace empty cells to a custom string on data import R

Tags: r

All I want is for the empty cells to be `Unassigned` for my imported data frame. But no. It either makes the empty values `NA` or does nothing. I have tried replacing the `NA` values with the string "Unassigned" but I keep getting errors. Here is what I have tried:

1:

```
 raw_data <- read.csv("taxonomy.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings="Unassigned")
```

2: Producing NA where empty cells are

```
raw_data <- read.csv("taxonomy.csv", na.strings=c("", "Unassigned"))
raw_data[is.na(raw_data)] <- "Unassigned"
```

Then getting error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I am so desperate for help!

Answer (score 0):

That's because raw_data is a factor variable.
Factor variables have a certain amount of levels and you cannot add one that is not included. Do this first:

```
levels(raw_data) <- c(levels(raw_data),"Unassigned")
```

This way "Unassigned" is now one of the possible levels of your variable.
You can now replace all the na as you were doing:

```
raw_data[is.na(raw_data)] <- "Unassigned"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately I still get the error.

Comment: that's strange. have you tried importing without the option na.strings?
I don't know what's your data like, but if na are only in some columns, you might have to use the levels() only on those columns, like:
levels(raw_data$var1) <- c(levels(raw_data$var1),"Unassigned")